# How to compare perfomance of queries via LINQ-to-SQL and plain SQL-Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, strongly-typed-dataset

I want to compare query execution performance of 3 methods:

- Query on Typed DataSet
- Query usingLINQ-to-SQL
- SQL-queries executed on SQL Server 2008 R2 directly

Therefore i'd like to run a few test szenarios which would be the following:

**Query on typed Dataset**

Here i've created the Dataset using the Dataset Desinger. I am then querying the corresponding TableAdapter like this

```
var minDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 1);
var maxDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 2);

var ta = new MyTableAdapter();
vat res = (from row in ta.GetData() 
              where row.Date >= minDat && row.Date <= maxDat
              select row).ToArray();
```

This results in a Timeout, as it would first get all the Data from the table in the database and execute the query on the received object. This is expected and fine.

**Query on typed Dataset**

I've created a LINQ-to-SQL Classes using O/R-Designer in Visual Studio

```
var minDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 1);
var maxDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 2);

var context = new LtSqlDataContext();

var query = (from row in context.MyTable
                where row.Date >= startTime && row.Date <= endTime
                select row).ToArray;   // I do the .ToArray() to actually receive the whole set of results, i guess here i am doing sth. wrong
```

This takes 2294 ms total. That seems reasonable so far.

**SQL Query**

Things are getting strange when comparing the execution time of the LINQ-to-SQL-Query with an actual SQL Query executed in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
declare @min datetime2 = '20140501';
declare @max datetime2 = '20140502';

select * 
    from MyTable 
    where   Date >= @min
        and Date <= @max
```

This takes a little more than 6 seconds, 6211 ms to be exact (taken from SQL Server Profiler - Batch Completed).

***How it this possible?***

I think maybe I didn't get the Concept of LINQ-to-SQL right. I thought calling `ToArray()` on the query would lead to actually transferring the queries tuples into an array. But how would that be faster (by approx. 3 times) than the query when executed on the server directly?

It there a better way to compare the Query performance of the 2 concepts?

*PS:* The query generated by LINQ-to-SQL is the same like the one executed in SQL Server Mgmt Studio

**EDIT:** 
The query generated by LINQ-to-SQL looks sth. like the following

```
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language Deutsch
set dateformat dmy
set datefirst 1
set transaction isolation level read committed

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Column1], [t0].[Column2], [t0].[Column3], [t0].[Column4], [t0].[Column5], [t0].[Date], [t0].[Column7]
FROM [Alle].[MyTable] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Date] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[Date] <= @p1)',N'@p0 datetime2(7),@p1 datetime2(7)',@p0='2014-05-01 00:00:00',@p1='2014-05-02 00:00:00'
```

I have tried executing it in SSMS but it still takes 6 or so seconds....

Comment: Are you saying when you profile the LINQ-to-SQL and the SSMS SQL examples, they appear identical in Profiler, except the SSMS SQL takes 6 seconds and the LINQ-to-SQL takes 2 seconds?

Comment: Yes. The queries are structured equally. ill post it the question as an edit..

Comment: so again; have you tried running the "exact one" query via sp_executesql rather than direct? this can metter. Also: you need to check the `SET` options for both; you can use `@@OPTIONS` to discover this ([more details here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/))

Comment: yes i have. its the same. i don't understand it either. i will give the options a try. but i have to read you link first.

Comment: its simply strange. i have now also executed the exact same setting as LINQ-to-SQL does in SSMS (within `sp_executesql`) and it still takes about 6 seconds. to be precise. I took the settings and query applied by LINQ-to-SQL from SQL Server Profiler and executed those in SSMS. I have no idea whats going on. Maybe, not all the data is transferred to the .NET part when the query is executed?

Comment: Perhaps the `ToArray` is still not loading the data. Perhaps you should use the object in some way to force it.

Comment: Thats what i thought too. but how can i accompish that without messing the "benchmark"? Like: in what way can i use all tuples in the .NET part so that it takes minimal costs..

Comment: There should be a property somewhere in LINQ that determines if the data is loaded..

Comment: idk. The funny thing is, SQL Server Profiler also says its performed in under 3 seconds. its super weird..

Comment: How many rows are returned? SSMS is slow with processing rows.

Comment: 565173 rows are returned.

Comment: Add `SET ROWCOUNT 0` to your SSMS query and see if it a similar time

Comment: Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).  Familiarize yourself with the investigation methodology then then compare the execution of the two queries. You'll find the answer yourself.

Comment: @ElectricLlama still 6 secs :(

Answer (score 1):

This *could* be down to the very different query construction - in particular, parameterization, and the type of datetime used. You could compare in SSMS to:

Or you could do the same in SSMS with simply:

```
declare @min datetime = '20140501', @max datetime = '20140502';

exec sp_executesql N'select * 
from MyTable 
where   Date >= @min
and Date <= @max', N'@min datetime, @max datetime', @min, @max;
```

To perform the same test in ADO.NET as a raw query, you would have a **parameterized** query, and pass in the values as regular `DateTime`, since that will compare well to the others:

```
var minDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 1);
var maxDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 2);
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = @"select * 
from MyTable 
where   Date >= @min
    and Date <= @max";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("min", minDat);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("max", maxDat);
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while(reader.Read()) {...}
    }
}
```

or perhaps more simply, with something like dapper:

```
var minDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 1);
var maxDat = new DateTime(2014, 5, 2);
var rows = conn.Query<SomeType>(@"select * 
from MyTable 
where   Date >= @min
    and Date <= @max", new { minDat, maxDat }).ToList();
```

where `SomeType` has properties that resemble the columns in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am willing to use a LINQ query which is equivalent to the one performed in SSMS. As far as i can tell, this is basically what i've done, i just wonder why it is faster using LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: @nozzleman the SSMS query you have posted is **not** equivalent to what LINQ-to-SQL is doing; that is the point of the first part of my answer. Have you tried the TSQL at the top of my answer? how does *that* perform?

Comment: It performs just like the original SSMS query. Maybe you can tell me, why LINQ-to-SQL is faster. This would answer my question. If i watch the generated query of the LINQ-to-SQL statement while debugging, its the same as the one i typed into query editor in SSMS. I am only wondering why LINQ-to-SQL ist faster. Thanks for your effort btw.

Comment: @nozzleman the main remaining option is `SET` options; these can have significant performance changes, and the SSMS defaults are not the same as the ADO.NET ones. Are you using anything exotic like calculated persisted indexed columns? (they *hate* `SET` options). But: there's no fundamental reason for LINQ-to-SQL to be faster - I suspect there are other differences. And I'm still pretty sure that L2S is going to use the parameterized form; I strongly suspect that what you're seeing as "the LINQ-to-SQL statement while debugging" is a white lie, for convenience ;p

Answer (score 0):

> How many rows are returned?

.

> 565173 rows are returned

There you go. SSMS is slow processing many rows. Your benchmark is invalid. Execute the LINQ query and the SQL query using ADO.NET from your app. Iterate through all rows. In the ADO.NET version, retrieve all column values to force deserialization.

Probably, the duration will now match rather closely, with ADO.NET being faster.

If LINQ to SQL is still faster there is something else going on such as a bad cached plan or SET options. For such a simple query I'd be surprised though.